# WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python

I am using the following script to add a copy right to all the files in the directories and subdirectories for a give directory passed as first argument ,am running the script as follows but running into below error...
can anyone provide inputs on ohw to fix it?

ERROR:-

```
C:\Dropbox\copyrights>python Add_copyright.py .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Add_copyright.py", line 69, in <module>
    prepend_file(fullname, dirpath)
  File "Add_copyright.py", line 60, in prepend_file
    os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

CODE:-

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile

file_patterns_to_match = ['*.c','*.h','*.cpp','*.txt']

headertext = """/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012-2013, The Linux Foundation. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Previously licensed under the ISC license by Qualcomm Atheros, Inc.
 *
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for
 * any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the
 * above copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all
 * copies.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL
 * WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR
 * PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER
 * TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR
 * PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
 */
"""

# make any newlines in headertext match the system line ending
headertext = headertext.replace('\n', os.linesep)

def want_this_file(fname):
    for pat in file_patterns_to_match:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, pat):
            return True
    return False

def prepend_file(fullname, path):
    # with statement means temp file is written and closed at end of with
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=path, delete=False) as out_file:
        # get the name immediately
        temp_fname = out_file.name

        try:
            # use binary mode to avoid newline translations
            with open(fullname, "rb") as in_file:
                out_file.write(headertext)
                shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, out_file)
        except Exception:
            # on any error, clean up temp file and re-raise exception
            try:
                os.remove(temp_fname)
            except Exception:
                print("unable to clean up temp file: " + temp_fname)
                pass
            raise
    # rename temp file to fullname, clobbering original
    os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)


start_directory = sys.argv[1]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_directory):
    for fname in filenames:
        if want_this_file(fname):
            fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
            prepend_file(fullname, dirpath)
```

Comment: File IO on Windows is such a pain... unintuitive and inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append to an existing file, you need something like:

`with open(fullname, "ab") as in_file`

Q: Are you sure you can use `shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, out_file)` with an open out_file that you've already written to?

Q: Do you know which line is causing the windows error?

Thank you for the update.

I'll bet your directory already has a file already named `fullname`, hence `os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)` fails with "file already exists".

Q: Would [shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) work instead?

Comment: Q: Were you able to resolve the problem by making sure either 1) the file doesn't exist before you rename the temp file, or 2) "move" instead of "rename" to overwrite whatever the original file was?