# python download & rename

Tags: python, csv, selenium, file-rename

I have a problem with my code

The purpose of this code is to download a csv file (which called history.csv) and rename this file to the original name which I use selenium to fetch it out of the web page.
the first issue here is selenium slowness while loading the web page.
the second issue is the code stopped after downloading and renaming the first 2 or 3 links of the links list.

here is the event list

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bJvxM9TZkhYXZOSnRDVnhTbFk/view?usp=sharing

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
events = open('events.txt', 'r')
for event in events:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(event)
    download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fxec_historytable"]/a').click()

    lname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fxit-h1title"]')
    lname = lname.text
    lname = lname.replace('\n', '')
    name = str(lname)
    print(name)

    path = "C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Downloads"
    os.chdir(path)
    print(os.getcwd())
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(file)
        nname = '{}{}'.format(name, fileExt)
        os.rename(file, nname)
```

an the error is

C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/us.py
Services Sentiment -European Monetary Union
C:\Users\Sayed\Downloads
ZEW Survey - Economic Sentiment -European Monetary Union
C:\Users\Sayed\Downloads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/us.py", line 21, in 
    os.rename(file,nname)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Services Sentiment -European Monetary Union.csv' -> 'ZEW Survey - Economic Sentiment -European Monetary Union.csv'

Comment: Add a check that there is no file already present with the name

Comment: or the best would be delete if any file is there with that name first

Comment: the folder is empty

Comment: if filename==name: os.remove(name) else: os.rename(filename, name)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is called out by Python:

> Cannot create a file when that file already
>
> exists:

I am not a Windows user, but per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.replace), you can try `replace()` instead of `rename()`. That should do it / replace the file silently.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/us.py", line 19, in <module>
    os.replace(filename, name)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Downloads' -> 'Consumer Price Index -Romania'

Answer (score 0):

I searched your error and found this old post:

[WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416456/windowserror-error-183-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists)

Looks like you have a for loop for renaming all files in folder "C:\Users\Sayed\Downloads" to a same 'name', is that right? If there are multiple files, there will definitely be name duplication or conflict.

Comment: name is variable not a string

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to rename all of the files to the same thing as the value of `name` does not change in your loop.

Comment: The thing everyone talks about is the name value which is a variable.the idea behind it to rename it automatically . Whatever the original name is or the given name is.

Comment: name is a variable, yes, but it is not set in the loop. Therefore, if in the first iteration its value is "myfile.txt", it will still have this value in the next iteration, and the next, and the next... and so on.